# Does there exist smooth or $C^2$ function for some infinite given points $a(n)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers, interpolation

I know that there exist some smooth function (polynomial) for finite numbers of values. The question is if there exists function (not necessary unique) which is twice differentiable and $f(n)=a(n)$?

Comment: Maybe splines can be used, but in order to apply them, you'd have to solve linear systems of infinite dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are such functions. You can take a pair of values $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ and find the polynomial of degree 5, which fulfills $p(n)=a(n)$, $p(n+1)=a(n+1)$, $p'(n)=p''(n)=p'(n+1)=p''(n+1)=0$. Putting all these polynomials together piecewise, the result will be $C^2$ and will interpolate all given values.

Note that you can achieve $C^k$ smoothness by requiring $p^{(\ell)}(n) = p^{(\ell)}(n+1)$ for $\ell=1,\dots,k$. In this case you'll need piecewise polynomials of degree $2k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x) = e^{4+1/(x^2-1/4)}, |x|<1/2, f(x) = 0, |x|\ge 1/2.$ Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}),$ the support of $f$ is $[-1/2,1/2],$ and $f(0)=1.$ The function

$$g(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb {Z}}a_nf(x-n)$$

then belongs to $C^\infty(\mathbb {R})$ and $g(n) = a_n$ for all $n.$

Comment: Is this function convex for $n>N$ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$? I need some convex or concave function.

Comment: You can't expect to do that. What if $a_n$ is the sequence $1,0,1,0,\dots$? Then $f'$ will take on the values $-1,1,-1,1,\dots$ hence can't be concave or convex after some point.

Comment: In my case i can assume that $a_n$ is decreasing. Furthermore i can take any subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: You keep adding conditions. Please be considerate of our time and try to state a complete problem.

Comment: For given decreasing sequence $a_n>0$ I'm trying to find convex or concave function with $f(n)=a_n$. I can also take any subsequence of $a_n$ instead of $a_n$.